# Problem with IR remote and Pushbutton for digispark

Tags: ir, attiny85

As digispark is more compact and suitable for my electrical application. Following the same procedure in [brtiberio answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18022/controlling-relays-with-ir-and-button/88579#88579). I tried to convert the script from Arduino UNO to digispark, but not succeed

```cpp
#define irPin 2
const int buttonPin1 = 0;
const int buttonPin2 = 4;
const int relay1 = 1;
const int relay2 = 3;
int Relay1State = 0;
int Relay2State = 0;
int master1State = 0;
int master2State = 0;
int button1State;
int button2State;
int lastButton1State;
long lastDebounceTime1 = 0;
int lastButton2State;
long lastDebounceTime2 = 0;
long debounceDelay = 50;
void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay1, Relay1State);
  digitalWrite(relay2, Relay2State);
}

void loop() {
  
  int key = getIrKey();

  if(key == 7388){
    Relay1State = !Relay1State;
    if(Relay1State == true)
      digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    else
      digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
  }

  if(key == 1778){
    Relay2State = !Relay2State;
    if(Relay2State == true)
     digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
   else
     digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
  }
}

int getIrKey(){
  int len = pulseIn(irPin,LOW);
  int key, temp;
  key = 0;
  //Serial.print("len=");
  //Serial.println(len);
  if(len > 6000) {
    for(int i=1;i<=32;i++){
      temp = pulseIn(irPin,HIGH);
      if(temp > 1000)
        key = key + (1<<(i-17));
    }
  }
  if(key < 0 )
    key = -key;
  
  //if(key)
    //Serial.println(key);

    delay(250);
  return key;
  //**********************//
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
  if (reading != lastButton1State) {
    lastDebounceTime1 = millis();
  }
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime1) > debounceDelay) {

    if (reading != button1State) {
      button1State = reading;

      if (button1State == HIGH) {
        master1State = !master1State;
        Relay1State = master1State;
      }
    }
  }

  digitalWrite(relay1, Relay1State);
  lastButton1State = reading;
    
  //*******************************//
  int reading2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  if (reading2 != lastButton2State) {
    lastDebounceTime2 = millis();
  }
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime2) > debounceDelay) {

    if (reading2 != button2State) {
      button2State = reading2;

      if (button2State == HIGH) {
        master2State = !master2State;
        Relay2State = master2State;
      }
    }
  }

  digitalWrite(relay2, Relay2State);
  lastButton2State = reading2; 
}
```

Any advise, please?

Comment: `not succeed` is not a description of a problem

Comment: Not sure why you means of "to convert the script from Arduino UNO to digispark"? [IRremote library](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote#supported-boards) does support DigiSpark (and ATtiny85) without the need of any conversion.

Comment: Which Arduino Core are you using? If you are running [ATTinyCore](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore), you can use the IRremote library without any problem.

Comment: The remote part is working well. the problem is with the push button function only. it dosen't works.

Comment: @Mah would you please share your final codes? I am in badly need of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button code is in the function `int getIrKey()`. But it never gets executed, because before it you execute `return key;`. With that you leave the function and returning the value of `key`. Everthing that comes after the return statement will not be executed.

Putting the button code in that function doesn't make sense in the first place (since the buttons are not used to "get the pressed IR key"). Instead try to put it in the `loop()` function, after the other relay code.

Comment: Thanks to chrisl. It is working fine now.

Comment: If you think my answer was correct, you can mark it as correct, so that others can see and learn from that.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that.